# Android Studio LayoutParams.weight not working

Tags: android, android-studio, layoutparams

I currently use LayoutParams to set layout_width and layout_height programmatically:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 215);
tvText.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Now I want so set the weight, but the "code can't be resolved". This both ways don't work:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 215, 1f);
tvText.setLayoutParams(lp)
```

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 215);
lp.weight=1;
tvText.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` in both places you currently have that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :)